# Fetching all the strings in a python list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have this list of lists

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,'normal'],[1,2,3,4,'abnormal'],[1,2,3,4,'normal'],[1,2,3,4,'ab
normal'],[1,2,3,4,'normal'],[1,2,3,4,'abnormal'],[1,2,3,4,'abnormal'],[1,2,3,4,'
abnormal']]
```

I want to extract all the strings perse I have no idea what these strings might be, and count each string occurance.
Is there a simple loop instruction to do that ?

Comment: Just use a nested `for` loop and check if each element `isinstance(element, str)`

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure to have understood your question (word "perse" is unknown to me) If you want to count the occurence of strings normal and abnormal, I propose that:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter([elt[4] for elt in a])
```

Outputs:

```
Counter({'abnormal': 5, 'normal': 3})
```

Comment: Maybe this was meant with "perse": https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/per_se

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count the number of occurrences and keep track of the string, loop over each item and add it to a dictionary

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,'normal'],[1,2,3,4,'abnormal'],[1,2,3,4,'normal'],[1,2,3,4,'abnormal'],[1,2,3,4,'normal'],[1,2,3,4,'abnormal'],[1,2,3,4,'abnormal'],[1,2,3,4,'abnormal']]

new={}
for b in a:
    for item in b:
        if type(item) is str:
            if item in new:
                new[item]+=1
            else:
                new[item]=1
print(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
count = 0
str_list = []
for arr in a:
    for ele in arr:
        if isinstance(ele, str):
            count += 1
            str_list.append(ele)
print count
```

The variable `count` holds the total number of strings in each list inside list a. While `str_list` will hold all strings

Here is the code snippet on repl.it: https://repl.it/Di9L